# Could Symfony2 works without UserProviders?

Tags: php, symfony

The reason of this question was born from a collaborator's request: I want to know if I can remove the provider. Is mandatory? I want to remove it if I can leave its methods empty.

So, in Symfony **providers** configuration is **mandatory**. Also i need to configure **at least one Provider**. Done! My custom providere is this:

```
final class CustomListener implements UserProviderInterface                                                                
{                                                                                                                          
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)                                                                          
    {                                                                                                                      
        // ...                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                      

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)                                                                       
    {                                                                                                                      
        return $user;                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                      

    public function supportsClass($class)                                                                                  
    {                                                                                                                      
        // ...                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                      
}
```

I can login. Logout. ... but I am a bit confused. Why an interface want these "useless", at the moment, `loadUserByUSername` and `supportsClass`? Useless in the meaning of: I have empty implementation, and it works!!! Work, means that I set session manually with `$request->getSession()->set('firefall', $token);` and user is authenticated. I can logout users invalidating session.

I am sure that at least, this provider NEEDS that refreshUser return a UserInterface:

```
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)                                                                       
    {                                                                                                                      
        return $user;                                                                                                      
    }
```

Because login does not work without this return. But I can leave other methods empty.

I've looked inside tests and in `UserProviderInterface` method's comments. But nothing. I didnt get if I can:

- remove provider;
- I am missing something in the documentation;
- I am trying to badly use Symfony (it is possible);
- I am a Teapot;
- ...
  -

And, .... Why login does not work when I comment this line even if My firewall does not use this provider?

```
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)                                                                       
    {                                                                                                                      
        // return $user;                                                                                                      
    }
```

--

I've created this `CustomListener` just because I've defined 
a service as provider. Then I've received this message:

Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user provider tells Symfony where to load the users from, so you need one, but you don't need to create your own unless you have a complex authentication system.

If you're loading the users from the database you can use the default db provider http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: I have not a database. I've just an API for users authentication, and also for provide the data. I am not using Doctrine.

Comment: If you're using an API, how does your authentication works with an empty user provider ? how does Symfony know how to load the users ? you must have something else doing the same job

Comment: Inside a controller, I use an HTTP client that ask the API if credentials are good, and if it returns to me some particular value, I do this: `$request->getSession()->set('_security_secured_area', $this->token->createFromRequest($request));`

Comment: Your authentication logic should be inside the authentication provider not in a controller, and it's a bad practice to override the _security session vars, you can use this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html or just google Symfony api authentication, lots of examples out there

Comment: Mmmm you are my rubberduck! Thank you. I'll fix some stuffs, ... Uh, ... what a bad question I've done =(